Problem in the formatage of a doctest using numpy matrix
Let us assume that I have code in Python a function f taking one numpy matrix parameter.
I do not understand why the following doctest succeed
>>> f(U) - np.matrix([[ 2.31162781,  1.82477741,  1.24472846],
    ...               [ 0.94238217,  2.02704758, -1.18379487],
    ...               [-1.05447421, -2.26815559, -1.76702953],
    ...               [ 0         ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
    matrix([[ 0.,  0., -0.],
            [-0., -0.,  0.],
            [ 0., -0.,  0.],
            [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])

while the following one failed:
>>> f(U)
matrix([[ 2.31162781,  1.82477741,  1.24472846],
        [ 0.94238217,  2.02704758, -1.18379487],
        [-1.05447421, -2.26815559, -1.76702953],
        [ 0         ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])

Here is the failure report:
**********************************************************************
File "__main__", line 26, in __main__.f
Failed example:
    f(U)
Expected:
    matrix([[ 2.31162781,  1.82477741,  1.24472846],
            [ 0.94238217,  2.02704758, -1.18379487],
            [-1.05447421, -2.26815559, -1.76702953],
            [ 0         ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
Got:
    matrix([[ 2.31162781,  1.82477741,  1.24472846],
            [ 0.94238217,  2.02704758, -1.18379487],
            [-1.05447421, -2.26815559, -1.76702953],
            [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   4 in __main__.f
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.


I do not think this is related to the implementation of f... But probably to an internal mecanism of numpy that I do not know or understand.

There's no . on the first 0 in the last row of the expected output. Use a diff tool next time - it'll spot that for you.
